# How to map JSON response object with nested array to state

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

My goal is to display content of a JSON Object -if available! otherwise display "add new data".

**If there is no data from backend, create data for backend:**
I don't know yet if a function with useState is the best approach to make a "add new" stuff, where the user can add/save some data.. But know I need the "new user" data (as state params?) to sent them to my backend (Django) as post params.

**I don't know how to map JSON object to my state or to JSX elements..**
This is my main problem.

This is my JSON response from backend (this.props.user) when used console.log in browser:

```
0:
   avatar: "/media/default_l.png"
   birthday: "2020-09-14"
   user_settings:
      [0: "P26"],
   name: "Huso"
   gesellig: true
   verspielt: true
__proto__: Object
1:
   avatar: "/media/dog_default_l.png"
   birthday: "2012-04-24"
   dog_race: 
   [
     0: "A9",
     1: "B5"
   ],
   name: "Medo"
   gesellig: true
   verspielt: false
```

-> I added the '[' and ‘]‘ since they where not visible in Chrome..

I have converted the JSON object to string, since it was no valid JSON object (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1) using var array = JSON.stringify(this.props.user); Now the format is correct and the array looks just like the example above and as I need it. BUT now typof(array) returns string... how do I convert this string exactly as it is to an array so that I can use the map function?

If i try to **map** it, i get either "map is not a function" or "detected object with keys" or other errors..

To be able to use the data as the state, I think need this objects to be save as follows:

```
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { avatar: '/media/default_l.png',
          birthday: '2020-09-14',
          name: 'Huso',
          gesellig: true,
          verspielt: true,
          user_settings: [
            {settings: 'P26'},
          ],
        },
        { avatar: '/media/default_l.png',
          birthday: '2012-04-24',
          name: 'Medo',
          gesellig: true,
          verspielt: false,
          user_settings: [
            {settings: 'A9'},
            {settings: 'B5'},
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
```

-> "settings" will be a multi select box, gesellig will be a checkbox..

I can handle this shape/array! The mapping of the state array "users" works:

```
       <div className="div-settings">
        {this.state.users.map((user)=>
          <div>
            <span>user.dogname</span>
            <span>user.birthday</span>
            <span>user.gesellig</span>
             <span>user.verspielt</span>
             <img className='user-avatar' src={user.avatar} alt='avatar' />
             <ul>
              {user.user_settings.map((s,index)=>
                <li key=index}>{s.settings}</li>
               )}
              </ul>
              </div>
          )}
        </div>

      </div>
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to bring the JSON response into this shape of array, or more accurate, how to map the JSON response to the JSX elements like I do with the state array.

I know there are lots of examples on stackoverflow, with Object.keys but when i try them I get the "its not a function" errors and others.. When I try to save the JSON Data into a new array like so

```
const {array} = JSON.stringify(this.props.user)
```

-> The output with console.log is `{}`  or  `{...}` .

Maybe someone has a good approach for such JSON/maping/displaying stuff?
I also want to sent edited params later back as post parameters.
Would be very happy if someone could explain a fitting solution! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: **SOLUTION FOUND!** [How to convert string to array in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264017/how-to-convert-string-to-array-in-react-js/64264954#64264954)

Might someone of the users, which are able to mark this question as duplicate, could please tag this question appropriately.

Comment: Not really, no.. Chrome is displaying (2) [{…}, {…}] but when I expand it shows the JSON objects as written above. The "[" inside where the "settings" are, are also shown in Chrome when collapsed.. I don't understand what diff. this would make? Does this mean I need to use the Objec.keys(this.props.user) first and then inside the .map-function or a forEach? I want the Json to be inside of <div className="div-settings">....

Comment: EDIT: typeof this.props.user === "object"; returns "true" so it is an object. But still, I cannot JSON.parse without errors, and JSON.stringify returns {} or noting.