# How to convert string to array in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a JSON object that I cannot handle without
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

So i made a string out of it
`var array = JSON.stringify(this.props.user);`

Now that string has the format I neet to loop through it / to use map function
**BUT it is a string**. How can I bring this string into an valid array to be able to loop through it?

What I have as JSON object (copied from Chrome, typeof(..) returns object):

```
0:
avatar: "/media/dog_default_l.png"
birthday: "2020-09-14"
user_settings: ["P26"]
name: "Huso"
gesellig: true
verspielt: true
__proto__: Object
1:
avatar: "/media/dog_default_l.png"
birthday: "2012-04-24"
user_settings: (2) ["A9", "B5"]
name: "Medo"
gesellig: true
verspielt: false
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This object as string (copied from console.log):

```
[{"name":"Huso","birthday":"2020-09-14","gesellig":true,"verspielt":true,"avatar":"/media/dog_default_l.png","user_settings":["P26"]},{"name":"Medo","birthday":"2012-04-24","gesellig":true,"verspielt":false,"avatar":"/media/dog_default_l.png","user_settings":["A9","B5"]}]
```

What I need is an array (to be able to loop through):

```
users: [
        { avatar: '/media/dog_default_l.png',
          birthday: '2020-09-14',
          name: 'Huso',
          gesellig: true,
          verspielt: true,
          user_settings: [
            {settings: 'P26'},
          ],
        },
        { avatar: '/media/dog_default_l.png',
          birthday: '2012-04-24',
          name: 'Medo',
          gesellig: true,
          verspielt: false,
          user_settings: [
            {settings: 'A9'},
            {settings: 'B5'},
          ],
        },
      ],
```

Object.entries, Object.keys etc. on the JSON object return or {} or nothing.
I don't know if there is a way of getting this object looped?
**I'm really stuck and hope someone has a solution that works.**
This question is related to [How to map JSON response object with nested array to state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64243563/how-to-map-json-response-object-with-nested-array-to-state/64263353#64263353) since nobody answers there.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse()` to return it back to an object?

Comment: your `unexpected token` error is probably happening because you *don't* have a JSON string; it's already been parsed.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger yes I did and when I did I saw that I am getting back the orignal format -> I already had a valid array but the amount of tries and failures just kinda made me nuts. I have now used Object.entries to eliminate the keys from the object, now I can handle it as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that the JSON is already valid, I was just too confused and irritated by the errors with different usages of Object.keys etc.!

I've solved the issue with:

```
const arr = Object.entries(this.props.user);
const mapped = [];
arr.forEach(([key, value]) => mapped.push(value));
```

This way I am cutting out the {} entries inside the object and saving them to an array, with which I can map and render the data inside as follows:

```
..

return(
<div>
 {mapped.map((user)=>
   <div>
     <b>{user.name}</b>

...
```

Comment: You can just `map` the array instead of looping each item and pushing to the `mapped` variable. Please mark the answer as correct if it is suitable :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have an array of objects. `typeof` the variable is returning `Object` because Arrays are Objects.

So you can do whatever you want with the array like `map`, `filter`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That brought me back to how to use Object.entries correctly. I've solved the issue with
```
const arr = Object.entries(this.props.user);
const mapped = [];
arr.forEach(([key, value]) => mapped.push(value));
```
This way I am cutting out the {} entries inside the object and saving them to an new array, with which I can map the data inside.